Construct a non-abelian group $G$ such that $g^3=1$ for all $g\in G$, where 1 is the identity.
The intuition to ask this question comes from an exercise in Basic Algebra I (question 1.4.3). The question is "Show that any group in which every a satisfies $a^2=1$ is abelian. What if $a^3=1$ for every $a$?" The question itself is not hard to solve. Let the group be $G$, by Sylow's Theorem, we have $\vert G\vert=3^n$. We can construct $G$ by semi-direct product and $G=\langle a,b,c\vert a^3=b^3=c^3=1,ab=ba,ac=ca,bc=cab\rangle$. However, since Jacobson wrote this question in section 1.4 (generalized associativity, commutativity), where semi-direct product and Sylow's Theorem are not mentioned, I suppose there should be a more intuitive construction with the terms he introduced. Here is a list of all terms mentioned from 1.1 to 1.4: monoid, group, direct product, isomorphism, Cayley's Theorem, generalized associativity, and commutativity. Is there any construction of $G$ that only involves those concepts? Thanks in advance.

Hint: by Cayley's theorem, every finite group can be thought of as a group of permutations.  Can you make a group of permutations where every element has order three?

The smallest non-Abelian permutation group with this property lives in $S_9$. I'm not convinced there's an easy way to see this with what's been done in the book so far. I read the question more as like a "brainteaser" to consider, not necessarily fully solve at this point.

Its hard to believe you learned about monoids w/o learning about matrices

To get $|G|=3^n$ Cauchy suffices. This at least leaves out the more advanced Sylow.

Consider the Heisenberg group of matrices:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}1&x&y\\0&1&z\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]$$
where $x,y,z$ come from the field $\mathbb Z_3$.
Note that
$$\left[\begin{matrix}1&x&y\\0&1&z\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]^3=\left[\begin{matrix}1&3x&3xz+3y\\0&1&3z\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]$$
but the group is non-abelian.

Even matrices (nor fields nor rings) have not been discussed in the book at the point of the exercise.

Surely if you're reading Jacobson you're expected to be familiar with matrices, and with the integers modulo three.

That's not how I read the OP's question, but to each their own.

I agree with @SteveD.  This doesn't answer the question

I can write the multiplication table for the group. However, from my perspective, this is the easiest construction for a group where $g^3=1$ for all $g\in G$ but $G$ is non-abelian.

@Lucenaposition: I think this is a fine answer, and I upvoted it; there are many well-known constructions of this group, and this one is perfectly fine. I just don't think the OP's question (as asked) has an answer. As I mentioned in my comments above, I think Jacobson's question is more "food for thought" than "solve this problem". It's meant to pique curiosity, and so is not bound by the restrictions of what's already been developed in the text. As such, I think OP's semidirect product construct (or your matrix representation) are the intended outcome.
